# How to apply function to every cell in pandas in a fast way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

My issue is the following:
I need to apply a operation to every cell in a pandas dataframe. Like this I have the mean and std column wise of all the dataframe in a variable:

```
columnWiseMeans = df.mean(axis=0)
columnWiseStd = df.std(axis=0)
```

Then in each cell is is not 0 I normalise them:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
  for j in range(df.shape[1]):
    if df.iloc[i, j] == 0:
        continue
    else:
        df.iloc[i, j] = (df.iloc[i, j]-columnWiseMeans[j])/columnWiseStd[j]
        print(f'in {i},{j} value {df.iloc[i, j]}')
```

After collect the mean and std row-wise and do the same:

```
rowWiseMeans = df.mean(axis=1)
print(rowWiseMean[0])
rowWiseStd = df.std(axis=1)
print(rowWiseStd[0])

for i in range(df.shape[0]):

  for j in range(df.shape[1]):
    if df.iloc[i, j] == 0:
        continue
    else:
        df.iloc[i, j] = (df.iloc[i, j]-rowWiseMeans[i])/rowWiseStd[i]
        print(f'in {i},{j} value {df.iloc[i, j]}')
```

The problem here is that this is very slow as I have a [~70k, ~70k] dataframe. I have tried with applymap which is faster but I don't know how to tell it that if is 0 skip it and it to let me know in which position it is to use a specific mean and std. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: you can pass in a check using lambda or use something like a drop function to get rid of zeros / blank

Comment: I don't want to get rid of the zeros, I want them to stay but I do not want them to be in the normalisation.

Comment: you won't alter the data in the dataframe when running those functions, just the calculation will be done with the drops.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I see you are assigning element per element, in general manipulate the whole dataframe will be faster.

A few tests I ran on my machine with a (10k x 10k) array created with numpy.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
r = np.random.rand
```

- Generate data in 2.5 seconds

```py
N = 10000
dnp = np.random.randn(N, N) * r(N, 1) * r(1, N) + r(1, N) + r(N, 1);
df = pd.DataFrame(dnp);
```

- Compute using dataframes 6.5 second

This is probably what you look for. It would run in about 5 min for your dataframe.

```py
df = (df - df.mean(axis=0)) / df.std(axis=0)
df = (df - df.mean(axis=1)) / df.std(axis=1)
```

- Faster compute using numpy (3 seconds)

If your data frame has uniform type (e.g. all entries are float64), then you can convert it to a numpy array, compute using numpy and go back to the dataframe representation.

```py
dnp = np.array(df)
dnp[:,:] = (dnp - dnp.mean(axis=0)) / dnp.std(axis=0)
dnp[:,:] = (dnp - dnp.mean(axis=1)) / dnp.std(axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np);
```

If you can use 32-bit numbers then you could do  `dnp = np.array(df, dtype=np.float32)` and it would run in 1.5 second.

#### Python loops

Python is interpreted, as you can see in the above solutions you do everything in a few python instructions. In your example you are running several loops. I see that you even checked for a zero to avoid calculating one element, that's probably not helping, because each instruction in python has an overhead. Consider the following example.

```py
t = 0
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        t += 1
```

It is less than the overhead you would have, and it takes 10 seconds (for a 10k x 10k matrix). This would take about 9 minutes to run with `N=70k`.

#### Edit 1: Avoiding nan

As mentioned in the comments, some rows/columns may end up with nan, this must be a `0/0` issue. It will happen when all the elements say `x[i] = c` for all `i`, it means that the `mean(x) = c` and `std(x) = 0`, thus `(x[i] - mean(x))/std(x) = (c - c) / 0 = 0 / 0`.

One possible solution is to set these values to `0` instead. This can be achieved with no significant additional cost as follows:

```
df = (df - df.mean(axis=0)) / df.std(axis=0).replace(0, 1)
df = (df - df.mean(axis=1)) / df.std(axis=1).replace(0, 1)
```

the [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method will set the result to 1 whenever it finds a zero, as a result the expression above will become `(c - c) / 1 = 0`.

If for any other reason std is producing `nan` you can use the [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method

```
df = (df - df.mean(axis=0)) / df.std(axis=0).fillna(1).replace(0, 1)
df = (df - df.mean(axis=1)) / df.std(axis=1).fillna(1).replace(0, 1)
```

This solution simply skips the normalization of rows/columns where the standard deviation returned `nan`.

Comment: Thank you. I will check, but in the calculation how I'm skipping the zeros? Because some columns or rows are indeed 0 and doing the whole normalisation gives me NaNs and that breaks everything.

Comment: In that case you should be checking if the calculated standard deviation is zero not if an individual element is zero, consider the case (1,2,3), when you subtract mean you have(-1,0,1), you have standard deviation sqrt(2/3), but you have one zero in the array. On the other hand the example [1,1,1] will have no zero, but the standard deviation is zero and it will produce nan.

Comment: Yes, before I was, then I settled with the easiest way to see first the results then optimise them. Is the div which is causing the issues as for some cells it ends up being 0 so I need to check before I do the normalisation. Your code looks very good but still has that issue.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you this looks like it will solve this problem! I'll check it tomorrow and get back to you. :D